# What is the sum of this series $\sum_n {(1/2^{2n}+1/3^{2n+1})}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the sum of this series 
$$ \sum_{n\in \Bbb N} {\left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}+\frac{1}{3^{2n+1}}\right)}
$$

I just want to know what am I doing wrong!

Well I have split the series into 2 other series to obtain this relation: 
$$\sum_n \frac{1}{2^{2n}} + \sum_n \frac{1}{3^{2n}} 
$$
Then I'm using the geometric series with ratio of $\frac{1}{2^2}$ for the first series and the ratio of $\frac{1}{3^2}$ for the second one.
We know that the sum of a geometric series is $$s=\frac{1}{1-q},$$ where $q$ is the ratio. I calculated the sums but i get a wrong result.

Comment: Your question seems to be completely unclear. Can you clarify $sum_n {1/2^{2n}+1/3^{2n+1}}$?

Comment: Notice that $(1/2)^{2n} = ((1/2)^2)^n = (1/4)^n$. Can you simplify $(1/3)^{2n+1}$ similarly?

Comment: As an FYI, please do not use all caps in a post unless it is abbreviating something - it gets interpreted as shouting and is quite disrespectful.

Comment: Some authors have natural numbers start at $0$ and some at $1$. Depending on what your book is using the first term of your geometric series need not be $1$, hence the formula you are using for the sum needs to be modified. $a/(1-r)$, where $a$ is the first term of the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{3^{2n+1}}=\frac13\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{3^2}\right)^n=\frac13\frac{1}{1-\frac19}$$